# How to use fractal transformer in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I try to use the [Fractal library from The PHP League](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/serializers/) in my project

I have model: `Object` with fields `id, name`. It has relation `prototypes` as one to one.

So, model `Prototype` has relation `Fields`. Where model `Fields` contains fields: `name, id`.

Also there is separated model: `ObjectFields` that contains values for each object fields. For example:

```
object_id | value
1            1
```

In result I need to get output JSON:

```
objects : {
   "id" : 1,
   "name" : "Weapon",
   "prototype": {
      "id" : 1,
      "name" : "Prototype Name",
      "fields" : {
          "field_name" : ObjectFields.value
      }
   }
}
```

Look please on

```
"fields" : {
  "field_name" : ObjectFields.value
}
```

so, It would be field name as key and value from model ObjectFields.

Now I do request using query as:

```
Object::with("prototype.field.name.value");
```

It returns me nested output object, but I need that last 3 realations will be in one object by key `field.name`